# Rails, Scriptaculous, effect where one element pushes another out of the way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scriptaculous

I really like the visual effect where a new element seems to push an old element out of the way. Pretty common thing recently.

here is a static example.
http://github.com/

However, I'm trying to do it with recently updated products. Also would like to use scriptaculous if at all possible with periodically_call_remote using ruby on rails.

Comment: You should formulate a question.

Comment: How can you make the visual effect  at http://github.com/ with scriptaculous using dynamic ruby on rails, periodic_call_remote, and dynamic content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without writing the code for you, here are the pieces you need to build:

- an action in Rails that returns the new html. This will most likely `render :partial`
- a PrototypeJS `Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater` to grab the html, and update the div with new items
- in the updater's success handler, you want to ease the new elements in - use a scriptaculous effect to show the new html into the div, pushing the other elements out of the way. (not sure how you want to do this - you might have to `move` the existing elements down to accomodate the new ones, but do it slowly. I recommend you get the first two bullets working *and then* worry about the effects).

There's no specific need to use `periodic_call_remote`, it can be done entirely with unobtrusive javascript.